# Simple Java Applet not loading in FireFox / Safari on MacOS

Tags: java, applet

I'm probably missing something very basic here. I'm trying to get my first applet to run inside a local HTML page in Firefox 3.6 on Mac OS 10.5.8. Here's the applet's code:

```
package SimpleApplet;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyApplet extends Applet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void init()
{
}

public void stop()
{
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
g.drawString("Tweedle-Dee!",20,40);
} 

}
```

Here's the HTML page:

```
<html>
<body>
Here's the applet: <br/>
<applet code="MyApplet.class" width="300" height="150">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Both files (.class and .html) are in the same folder on my local machine. Now when I load the .html file into Firefox, a rectangle with a red X gets displayed. The applet works when started from Eclipse (using JRE 1.5 BTW).

Also, it's not a general problem with my browser, as several pages with applets (e.g. http://java.sun.com/applets/jdk/1.4/demo/applets/Blink/example1.html) work.

This is also difficult to troubleshoot because there is no output at all on the Java console...

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had to move MyApplet.class into a subfolder called SimpleApplet.

Answer (score 1):

Try omitting the .class

This in combination with using the object tag I had better results.

```
<object classid="java:com.something.fullyQualifiedClassName">
            <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet">
</object>
```

also see my question and specifically the selected answer, as this is simular to what i had experienced

[What's wrong with my object tag to embed a Java Applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730183/whats-wrong-with-my-object-tag-to-embed-a-java-applet)

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't improve things.

Comment: See my edit. I had better results getting things to work using the object tag. That and the applet tag has been deprecated since HTML4.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info, but I tried that, still with the same results.

Comment: I'd suggest reading the documentation that is linked in my question's answer. That will most likely point you in the correct tweaks to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
package SimpleApplet;
```

And this means you won't need it in a folder called SimpleApplet.